# Move the same elements into only one parent

Tags: jquery, css

For example, I have HTML like :

```
<div class='date-outer'>
 <h2 class='date-header'></div>
 <div class='date-posts'>
   <div class='plook'></div>
   <div class='plook'></div>
 </div>
</div>
<div class='date-outer'>
 <h2 class='date-header'></div>
 <div class='date-posts'>
   <div class='plook'></div>
   <div class='plook'></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I want use Jquery to move class `plook` into only `date-posts` like:

```
   <div class='date-outer'>
     <h2 class='date-header'></div>
     <div class='date-posts'>
       <div class='plook'></div>
       <div class='plook'></div>
       <div class='plook'></div>
       <div class='plook'></div>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class='date-outer'>
     <h2 class='date-header'></div>
     <div class='date-posts'>
     </div>
    </div>
```

How can I do that? Thank for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use **[.detach()](https://api.jquery.com/detach/)** along with [**.append()**](https://api.jquery.com/append/) in order to achieve your task. Additionally you have to use `:first` to filter out the `first element` in the collection, since `$('.date-posts')` will return two elements in your current context.

Try,

```
$('.date-posts:first').append($('.plook').detach());
```

See the demo and Please inspect it to see the results.

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/Tx5rx/)